# Error occurred while clicking site settings of admin in my dnn website

Tags: dotnetnuke-7

I have a dnn site (DNN 7), i mean it's default site only, i have added a child portal for that site,
at first to add new logo i went to the admin-> site settings page and changed the logo. No problem in that, but after changing the skin, the next day again i went to the same admin->site setting options to change the logo, but i got an error that,

```
A critical error is occurred

DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Selection out of range
Parameter name: value ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Selection out of range
Parameter name: value
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable dataSource)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)
   at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.PerformSelect()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBox.DataBind()
   at DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls.DnnSkinComboBox.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

If anyone got this error and cleared, please help me...

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Check my blog for this error http://bestvisualization.blogspot.com/2014/08/site-setting-giving-error-in-dnn-731.html I put the answer there

Comment: @Rashid Heya, I can see your comment used to be an answer. It was probably converted to a comment because it is merely an offsite link. If you're willing to share though, I'd suggest you post an answer again, and include the gist (or even crosspost the entire content) of your blog post on SO as well, so others can easily spot the answer. This would also allow OP to accept your answer as the solution.